Acquire 2D real world coordinates after calibrating the camera
I have a camera that is mounted topview of an object from 20cm distance, the distance is fixed and the camera does not move nor has any rotations or transformations. The object that it overlooks is also fixed dimensions - 15x15cm. I have calibrated the camera using OpenCV (copy-paste from https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dc/dbb/tutorial_py_calibration.html) - with a printed chessboard of exactly same dimensions as the object is (8x8 board, each square 18.75mm), stored the intrinsic camera parameters and used it apply lens correction on each frame during frame acquisition using VideoCapture.
Now my goal is to have a real-time, real world coordinate system so that if you were to point a cursor on the GUI on a live feed, I'd get real world coordinates from the pixel.
I imagine this is quite a popular problem, I saw some discussions about  3D reconstruction using rotation and transformation vectors via OpenCV.solvePnP for perspective projection, but I believe since the camera is expected to be fixed, with fixed distance from the object of interest which is also fixed dimensions, I can emit those calculations, making my case simpler - unless I'm missing something.
How can I achieve the calculation of real-world coordinates in this case?
Are there some code examples?
What is this process called in computer vision? Reconstruction?
Would also be nice to know mathematical theory behind the process.
Thanks.

In your question it is not clear if the object is planar. Assuming it is, that the camera is well calibrated and, finally, that the camera extrinsic parameters are defined with respect to a world coordinate frame whose XY plane is the same as the object's (i.e. your object and the calibration target have the same thickness when placed on the same support), then you have a couple of options:

You trust that your setup is well manufactured and the object is really on the world XY plane. Then all you need to do is backproject pixels into rays in world coordinate frame, and scale the rays' lengths so that their Z components are equal to camera center's world Z coordinate.
You only trust that the object is planar, but may lay on a different plane than the calibrated world's XY. You then need to figure out what that plane is. Depending on the surface properties of your object, you may approach this problem through feature matching, i.e. matching well-known visible points to their nominal location on the object, and then use solvePnP. Or you may use a different sensor - e.g. a laser rangefinder. Once you have estimated the object's plane (e.g. as point and normal) in world coordinates, all you need to do is backproject the pixels into rays and intersect the rays with the the plane.


Thanks for the answer, sorry that I wasn't very clear in my question.  The object is indeed planar and the camera is positioned directly above the object. To actually correct myself object is 15x15cm, It might be smaller, but never bigger. We can even assume that it is exactly 15x15cm for the sake of simplicity of the question.
How is backprojection of pixels in a world coordinate frame done? I am not really familiar with the theory so not very confident in understanding this.
Thanks.

Re: backprojection. If you are using OpenCv, look at the documentation and examples for cv::undistortPoints.
